# Netsuite PHP toolkit giving error Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] Could not determine customer compid in

Tags: php, netsuite, sandbox, php-toolkit

I am trying `Netsuite PHP toolkit`. I am working with `Sandbox` account.
I have provided all the requirement but on adding a new customer its giving error as .

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[soapenv:Server.userException] Could not determine customer compid.

define("NS_ENDPOINT","2017_2");
define("NS_HOST","https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com");
define("NS_EMAIL","example@gmail.com");
define("NS_PASSWORD","xyz-2");
define("NS_ROLE","1030");
define("NS_ACCOUNT","12345_SB1");
define("NS_APPID","XUYZ-0218-4F5E-9078-5524E8EEF339");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the NS_ACCOUNT value to your standard NS account ID.  I had to do that even when I was working in the sandbox, previously.

Comment: I solved it. the NS_HOST should be https://NS-Accountid-SB1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  That is very weird.  I've never seen, or heard of, the NetSuite account being defined as a URL.  I'll keep that in mind, though, if I run into an issue like that again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Your endpoint should be 2017_2_0
2. Learn how to use the getDataCenterUrls call to get the account-specific host for NS_HOST.

Rule of thumb is the account-specific URL is something like https://NS_ACCOUNT.suitetalk.api.sandbox.netsuite.com for sandbox. Of course, replace NS_ACCOUNT with your account number. Don't bother with the _SB1 part.